# How to show axis ticks corresponding to plotted datapoints in a seaborn plot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn to plot some values which are numerical. But the each of those numbers correspond to a textual value and I want those textual values to be displayed on the axes. Like if the numerical values progress as 0, 5, 10, ..., 30; each of those encoded numbers must be linked to a textual description. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO :) If you think an answer has solved your problem, you might want to consider marking it "accepted" (green check mark). This will help the community to focus on questions which doesn't have satisfactory answers (and as a side, this will increase your & the author's reputation too). Don't recommend doing this if the answer didn't fully answer your question or you are hoping for a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Main Point:**

Use:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([<the x components of your datapoints>]);
ax.set_yticks([<the y components of your datapoints>]);
```

More elaborate version below.

---

You can go back to `matplotlib` and it will do it for you.

Let's say you want to plot [0, 7, 14 ... 35] against [0, 2, 4, ... 10]. The two arrays can be created by:

```
stepy=7
stepx=2
[stepy*y for y in range(6)]
```

(returning [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35])
and
    [stepx*x for x in range(6)]
(returning [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]).

Plot these with seaborn:

```
sns.scatterplot([stepx*x for x in range(6)],[stepy*y for y in range(6)]).
```

Give current axis to matplotlib by `ax = plt.gca()`, finish using [set_xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) and [set_yticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html):

```
ax.set_xticks([stepx*x for x in range(6)]);
ax.set_yticks([stepy*y for y in range(6)]);
```

The whole code together:

```
stepy=7
stepx=2

sns.scatterplot([stepx*x for x in range(6)],[stepy*y for y in range(6)])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([stepx*x for x in range(6)]);
ax.set_yticks([stepy*y for y in range(6)]);
```

Yielding the plot:

[image]

---

*I changed the example in the OP because with those numbers to plot, the plots already behave as desired.*